# Create a new SearchParameter

Tags: hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

EDIT

I have an instance of Microsoft FHIR Server and I would like to create a custom search parameter. I've created my SearchParamater resource and added it to the search-parameter.json definition file.
"\Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Core\Data\R5\search-parameters.json"

https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server/blob/master/docs/SearchArchitecture.md

I understand that a resource needs to be created or updated after the new search parameter is added, in order to be included in search results using this parameter.

I would like to know if there is a mechanism to allow a new search parameter to include all resources already existing in the server.

There must be something to trigger a re-index or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest code, you can trigger a reindex operation

```
POST /$reindex
```

**Testing before a full reindex**

You can force a reindex for just one resource:

```
POST /Patient/id$reindex
```

And also search for partially indexed resources by including the following header:
`x-ms-use-partial-indices`

**Custom indexes**

Going forward we're planning to have the ability to create and manage custom SearchParameters so you shuoldn't need to  modify the search-parameters.json file.

Comment: Oh, nice! I will give this new version a try. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Any tips on how to build the $reindex query. The FHIR server seems to expect a "Parameters" resource, and I don't know how to build it. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, I see... there is a not-implemented-exception for SQLServer implementation.

For future references:
`{
 "resourceType" : "Parameters",
  "parameter" : [{ 
    "name" : "maximumConcurrency",
    "valueInteger" : 1
  }]
}`

Comment: Correct, the sql provider is still coming. This is all very recent :)